# How to color every face of a box in VPython?

Tags: python-3.x, vpython

I want to make a Rubik's cube with VPython and I've faced a problem in the first stage! I want to color every face of a box with a different color but I can't find that! In the tutorial you only can color all of the faces of the box with one certain color!

What should I do?

Note: I'm using VPython 7 and Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make a box with different colored faces using a compound object made up of 6 pyramid objects each of a different color.

```
def cubelet(....): # a "factory function"
#create a list of the 6 pyramids with different colors; suppose its name is L

L = [pyramid(color=color.red,pos=vec(),axis=vec()), ... ]
return compound(L)

c = cubelet(....)
```

This "factory function" (a function that returns an object) returns an object that has the usual properties of primitive objects such as box. You can manipulate this compound object by changing c.pos or c.axis, etc. You can create copies of this cubelet:

```
c2 = c.clone(pos=vec(10,5,0), size=vec(2,1,0.2))
```

For pyramid see documentation

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/pyramid.html

Just arrange 6 of these in the shape of a box. For compound object see

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/compound.html

to make a compound object out of 6 pyramids.

Answer (score 0):

You can try make a box with different color faces out of 6 boxes similar to what is shown in this demo, where the box has red blue and grey faces.

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/Bounce-VPython

You can also make a compound object out of a number of objects.

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/compound.html

So you can make a compound object called multicolored box made out of six boxes of different colors.

You can also try creating your own box out of triangles and/or quads and color each face.

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/triangle.html